# What is the most efficient way to extract the last part of a split string in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, stored-functions

I want to extract the subdomain of a fully qualified domain up to the second level in a PostgreSQL function.

At the moment I have the following snippet which works, but I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way of doing it:

```sql
subdomains := left(query, length(query) - length(tld));
RETURN reverse(split_part(reverse(subdomains), '.', 1)) || tld;
```

It is guaranteed that the `query` ends with the `tld` substring.

Examples:

```
+---------------------+---------+---------------+
|        query        |   tld   |    output     |
+---------------------+---------+---------------+
| abc.example.com     | .com    | example.com   |
| x.y.z.example.co.uk | .co.uk  | example.co.uk |
| zzz.123.yyy.com.br  | .com.br | yyy.com.br    |
+---------------------+---------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

This one is not horribly efficient too but at least does not `reverse` twice and I guess that `array_length` is cheap and `string_to_array` is roughly as expensive as `split_part`. This may be wrong but is worth trying.

```
sd_arr := string_to_array(subdomains, '.');
RETURN sd_arr[array_length(sd_arr , 1)] || tld;
```

Somewhat better w/o variable assignment:

```sql
RETURN (select arr[array_length(arr,1)] from (select string_to_array(subdomains, '.') as arr) t) || tld;
```

Comment: Funny thing that I almost created the exact same alternative on my own in the meantime, it has performance benefits but is less than 1% unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is more efficient, but you can compare it to your implementation:

```
create or replace function get_domain(p_input text, p_tld text)
  returns text
as
$$
declare
  l_tld text[];
  l_items text[];
begin 
  l_tld := string_to_array(trim('.' from p_tld), '.');
  l_items := string_to_array(trim('.' from p_input), '.');
  return array_to_string(l_items[cardinality(l_items) - cardinality(l_tld):], '.'); 
end
$$
language plpgsql
immutable;
```

It essentially converts the input and the top level domain into arrays (stripping of any leading `.` to avoid empty array elements.

It then calculates the starting element to be returned by subtracting the length (=number of elements) of the tld from the length of the input. So for the input `x.y.z.example.co.uk` this is 6 - 2, which means it returns everything starting with the 4th element, which is then converted back to a "dotted" notation.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a3fdb7dc397ef329976585dbc1a1aa74)